# Totally Blank List view

Tags: php, android, listview, android-volley

I am working on custom Listview using volley .The main source is here [listview using volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

```
I have made just a little change
  (1)replace movies.json with my php url
  (2)here replace some string and comment some part because it not needed for me


package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater.CustomListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.model.Movie;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "myurl.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {


                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.seturl(obj.optString("image"));
                                Log.e("Test",obj.optString("image"));
                                movie.setfullname(obj.optString("fullname"));
                                movie.setRating(obj.optString("location"));

                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("location"));

                                // Genre is json array
//                          //  JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
//                              ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
//                              for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
//                                  genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
//                              }
//                              movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

my php code is

```
  <?php

            require_once('dbConnect.php');

            $sql = "select image,fullname,location from uploadfinding";

            $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


            $result = array();

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    array_push($result, array(
                        "image"=>$row['image'],"fullname"=>$row['fullname'],"location"=>$row['location']));


                echo "<pre>";       

                }

            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
```

But after only blank page display.
no idea what going wrong.
//log errors

```
04-30 18:00:25.788 5321-5353/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Restarter.getActivities
04-30 18:00:50.758 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.808 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.828 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.878 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.878 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.908 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.948 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:50.998 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.app.AppController.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.068 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
04-30 18:00:51.098 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
04-30 18:00:51.217 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.278 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.297 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.329 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.338 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.357 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.TaskStackBuilder', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.457 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.TaskStackBuilder', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.508 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.588 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.617 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.617 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.638 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.688 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.transition.TransitionManager', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.768 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.838 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.858 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:51.998 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:52.088 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:52.118 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
04-30 18:00:52.188 6781-6781/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.MainActivity.access$super
```

Comment: Have you defined your database name in your PHP?

Comment: Okay Try to  get the size of List<Object>.

Comment: Did you get the valley greater than 0?

Comment: Here you are using movie class.Isnt it?

Comment: List<Object> movieList=new ArrayList();  --->   movieList.add(movie) ---> movieList.size();

Comment: yes. movies class uses.. i have post the link from where i have do this.

Comment: Okay...Have you gotten values while printing it in Log.e("Test",obj.optString("image"));

Comment: Okay...Check whether the PHP code executes well in browser.

Comment: yes i am add the response here

Comment: Connected successfully
[{"image":"http:\/\/uploadfinding\/uploads\/2016-04-25 06:38:051461584281226.jpg","fullname":"ne0","location":"fgh"}]

Comment: This is your PHP code.Right?

Comment: I am not asking it. Post your PHP URL in browser.you could get the response like http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json,

Comment: on online server...and response is like that i have posted..

Comment: Can you please post your full code of Parsing JSon?

Comment: Where you have used setAdapter?

Comment: It is missing there...

Comment: customlistadapter is working for there .. plz see the above link carefully..

Comment: Try to move  "     adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);  "  line before---> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Have you gotten value in this   Log.e("Test",obj.optString("image"));?

Comment: Okay... Print Log.e("Test Error",String.valueOf(e)); inside of catch{Log.e( ...) }

Comment: Have you gotten any values in    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage()); line

Comment: both of them have no value in log..

Comment: Ooops!!!  Try this...  Log.d(TAG, response.toString()); .

Comment: If you not get the value at here,Problem may be in Json Structure.

Comment: But I checked that too by using the following link. It is valid Json only.https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: no value printed .. Its totally irritating.. btw thanx for ur effort..

Comment: Is there any error in Verbose / Log.e while running app?

Comment: Like MainActivity.class which is underlined...

Comment: see the log errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these lines in in your php file and change in the url with just results.json..

```
  $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($result));
fclose($fp);
```

I hope this will works for you..

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have following code in your xml

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Are you getting json response from url?

Comment: then check your php code because when you get some data as response then only you can able to list it out in listview.Make sure url is working or not or need to post any parameters to get data set from we end

Comment: He got the response like this...[{"image":"http:\/\/uploadfinding\/uploads\/2016-04-25 06:38:051461584281226.jpg","fullname":"ne0","location":"fgh"}]

Comment: In browser...It was posted by him.